# Screen show pixelated horizontal lines

Tags: display

I have this laptop:

> Msi katana gf66
> i7-11800H
> Rtx3060
> 64 Bit

When I am connecting screen to my laptop, (no matter what screen, I tried many screens) most of the screens shows `Out of range` and the ones that work shows the picture with pixelated horizontal lines.

I tried to reboot my laptop, updating drivers, deleting and reinstalling drivers, update windows, connection to more screen, using 4K HDMI cable,  and nothing can get this to work. Any other suggestions would help.

This is how the problem looks:
[image: this is how the problem looks]

Comment: Have you tried using different resolution and changing refresh rate? It might be the external displays can't keep up.